# Custom post type permalink returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules

Mates,

I've created a custom post type. Created some posts of that type, but when I try to access to any of them, I get 404 error. 
Also created single theme (single-pb_progproy.php).

Here's the code...

```
/*********************************************

    Programas/Proyectos

    *********************************************/
    class PB_ProgProy {
        public function __construct(){
            $this->register_post_type();
            $this->taxonomies();
            //$this->metaboxes();
        }

        public function register_post_type(){
            $labels = array(
                'name'                => __( 'Programas/Proyectos', 'text-domain' ),
                'singular_name'       => __( 'Programa/Proyecto', 'text-domain' ),
                'add_new'             => _x( 'Agregar Programa/Proyecto', 'text-domain', 'text-domain' ),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Agregar Programa/Proyecto', 'text-domain' ),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Programa/Proyecto', 'text-domain' ),
                'new_item'            => __( 'Nuevo Programa/Proyecto', 'text-domain' ),
                'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Programa/Proyecto', 'text-domain' ),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Buscar Programas/Proyectos', 'text-domain' ),
                'not_found'           => __( 'No se encontraron Programas/Proyectos', 'text-domain' ),
                'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No se encontraron Programas/Proyectos en la papelera', 'text-domain' ),
                'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Programa/Proyecto Padre:', 'text-domain' ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'Prog./Proy.', 'text-domain' ),
                'parent'              => __('Programa/Proyecto Contenedor', 'text-domain'),
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'              => $labels,
                'hierarchical'        => true,
                'description'         => 'Programas y Proyectos de OLADE',
                'taxonomies'          => array(),
                'public'              => true,
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'show_in_menu'        => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
                'menu_position'       => 25,
                'menu_icon'           => admin_url() . 'images/project.png',
                'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
                'publicly_queryable'  => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'has_archive'         => true,
                'query_var'           => 'progproy',
                'can_export'          => true,
                'rewrite'             => array(
                    'slug' => 'progproy/'
                    ),
                'capability_type'     => 'post',
                'supports'            => array(
                    'title', 'editor','page-attributes'
                    )
            );
            register_post_type('pb_progproy', $args );
        }

        public function taxonomies(){
            $taxonomies = array();

            $taxonomies['tipo'] = array(
                'query_var' => 'tipo_proy',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'tipo_proy'
                    ),
                'labels' => array(
                    'name'                => __( 'Tipo', 'text-domain' ),
                    'singular_name'       => __( 'Tipo', 'text-domain' ),
                    'add_new'             => _x( 'Agregar Tipo', 'text-domain', 'text-domain' ),
                    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Agregar Tipo', 'text-domain' ),
                    'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Tipo', 'text-domain' ),
                    'new_item'            => __( 'Nuevo Tipo', 'text-domain' ),
                    'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Tipo', 'text-domain' ),
                    'search_items'        => __( 'Buscar Tipos', 'text-domain' ),
                    'not_found'           => __( 'No se encontraron tipos', 'text-domain' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No se encontraron tipos en la papelera', 'text-domain' ),
                    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Tipo Padre:', 'text-domain' ),
                    'menu_name'           => __( 'Tipos', 'text-domain' ),
                    ),

                );

            $this->register_all_taxonomies( $taxonomies );
        }

        function register_all_taxonomies( $taxonomies ){
            foreach( $taxonomies as $name => $arr ) {
                register_taxonomy($name, array('pb_progproy') , $arr );
            }
        }


    }

add_action('init', function(){
    new PB_ProgProy();
});
```

I need friendly urls, so I configured wordpress to work with them.
The thing is that when I try to access, let's say...

```
http://olade.pbertran.dev/progproy/siee/
```

I get 404 error. 
I've been searching around, and couldn't find any solution.
Tried flush_rewrite_rules right after creating an instance of PB_ProgProy(), but still the same.

Any idea why this isn't working?

thanks in advance!

Pablo

Comment: try removing the slash from the rewrite slug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already flushed your WP_Rewrite rules? The easiest way to do that is just re-save your Permalink settings.

Comment: Already did. And still 404. Any ideas?